# is C# datatable make db query several times or only for the first time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

i have a Database table.This table is not frequently changes. But i need to retrieve  data from that table. i requirement is when the application start then it read all the record of that table and store it into the data Table. So, when needed that i just make query the record from data table not from the database. I already write the code. Now my question is : ** **when i call the method then is it this code query to database every time and create the DataTable every time or first fetch the data from db only once and store it into datatable until the application close?**** if not please help me to sort it out.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String RoomNumber = GetTable("xi");
    Console.WriteLine(RoomNumber);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string GetTable(string ShortCode)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataColumn column;
    DataRow row;

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    column.ColumnName = "Class";
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    column.ColumnName = "RoomNumber";
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    thisConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
    thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Class,RoomNumber FROM Section ";
    SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (thisReader.Read())
    {
        row = table.NewRow();

        row["Class"] = thisReader["Class"].ToString();
        row["RoomNumber"] = thisReader["RoomNumber"].ToString();
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    thisConnection.Close();

    DataRow[] result = table.Select("Class='" + Class + "'");
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in result)
    {
        RoomNumber = dataRow[1].ToString();
        //Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", dataRow[0], dataRow[1]);
    }

    //Console.WriteLine(RoomNumber);

    return RoomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us if your code does what you want? It really isn't clear. If you are asking us then what is stopping you testing this yourself?

Comment: i test it my self and its' working fine for one.. but what happen if i call the getTable function many times into the code base than what happen.. db query is running several times? or only once?

Answer (score 0):

This would load the data from the database into your DataTable when the program starts, and under the assumption that you do not invoke the GetTable method any other places, it will be run only once.

Comment: in here i just use the  GetTable("xi"); method only once.. but what happen if i use it several times into the full code base many of place? please suggest..

Comment: You should not.
The point you make is to load it into the DataTable, so after you have run the GetTable-method, all other queries should be against your table-object. You should devide your logic - one method for loading data into your DataTable, and another for extracting data from it. Load the data on startup like here, but call another method for quering the data.